# Java Matcher overreplacing groups

Tags: java, matcher

```
public class HexASCIITest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws DecoderException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String test = "src=\"test/__test/path/path2/AA_5F00_20140915_5F00_15_5F00_11_5F00_55_5F00_image_5F005F00_name.jpg\"";

    Pattern patternImages = Pattern.compile("src=\"[^\"]*?/__test/[^/]*?/[^/]*?/([^\"/]*?)\"");
    Matcher matcherImages = patternImages.matcher(test);

    while(matcherImages.find()) {
        String imageName = matcherImages.group(1);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_((?:[01234567890ABCDEF]{4}){1,})_");            
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imageName);

        while(matcher.find()) {     
            byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(matcher.group(1).toCharArray());       
            String imagePath = new String(bytes, "latin1");             
            imagePath = imagePath.replaceAll("\0", "");
            imageName = imageName.replaceFirst("_((?:[01234567890ABCDEF]{4}){1,})_", imagePath.trim());
        }           
        System.out.println(imageName);
    }   
}   
}
```

Hi guys, this is a program of mine, that should actually turn the HEX codes to ASCII, but it seems i am having logic problems, could anyone assist me ?

The initial image name is  : AA_5F00_20140915_5F00_15_5F00_11_5F00_55_5F00_image_5F005F00_name.jpg
After all of the replaces : AA_15_11_55__image_5F005F00_name.jpg

Which is not how it is supposed to work as the date 20140915 is gone and *5F005F00* is still there. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Noone can help me out with the logic ? I think i am wrong on the matcher replace part, tried a couple of things, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found it 
Regex should be - Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(*([0123456789ABCDEF]{4}){1,}*)");

Then - > byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(matcher.group(2).toCharArray());

and finally the replace 
imageName = imageName.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1), imagePath.trim());